# How to create a volt URL with parameters

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I want to create a URL using volt (Phalcon).

I have tried:

```
{{ url("order/view/", ["id" :order.id]) }}
```

However that produces a URL like:

```
http://localhost/gateway-new/order/view/?id=7
```

Whereas I would like the url to look like:

```
http://localhost/gateway-new/order/view/id/7
```

Any idea how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{ url("order/view/id/" ~  order.id) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you have a route defined like

```
$router->add('order/view/id/:int', array(
    'controller' => 'order', 
    'action' => 'view',
    'id' => 1))->setName('order-view');
```

you could use

```
{{ url(['for': 'order-view', 'id': order.id]) }}
```